# Selecting table data from a webpage

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, yql

I'm trying to get the results from empire magazine website (Film Reviews (Popular Matches) table) using YQL - http://www.empireonline.com/search/default.asp?search=Dragonheart (as an example) and I'm using firebug to get the xpath but it doesn't seem to want to return results. This is what I'm using;

`select * from html where url='http://www.empireonline.com/search/default.asp?search=cars' and xpath='/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table[2]'`

Now it seems to be able to use;

`select * from html where url='http://www.empireonline.com/search/default.asp?search=cars' and xpath='//table'`

But that's a whole lot of data I don't need to chuck about.

Comment: This is a **FAQ: browsers add mandatory HTML elements to the DOM** (like `head` and `tbody`), those `tbody` are not present in the source.

Comment: the best i got was the following-  SELECT * FROM html WHERE url="http://www.empireonline.com/search/default.asp?search=cars" and xpath="//table[3]//table[2]//table[2]//table[2]"

Comment: so is your problem solved? Sounds like the XPath in your comment does exactly what you need, right?

Comment: I think that the main problem is in the source html that you want to parse. It is declared as HTML 4.0 transitional, and it does not look well formed.

Comment: yeah running into all sorts of problems now :Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to be mindful when crafting the appropriate XPath query. The following gets the link and name of each of the reviews listed in that HTML table by first targetting the "*Film Reviews (Popular Matches)*" paragraph, then navigating to the list of films.

```
SELECT href, strong
FROM html
WHERE url   = 'http://www.empireonline.com/search/default.asp?search=Thor'
AND   xpath = '
    //p[.="Film Reviews (Popular Matches)"]
    /ancestor::table[1]
    /following-sibling::table[1]
    //td[2]/a
'
```

<sup>([Try this query in the YQL console](http://y.ahoo.it/pgU2wpjx).)</sup>